# CakePHP custom data source "READ" return structure

Tags: rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, datasource

I'm in the process of developing a custom datasource to interface with a REST API. In the example provided on the CakePHP website they return the data from a READ operation in this structure:

```
Array(
    'ModelName'=>Array(all the actual data here)
)
```

The code looks like:

```
return array($model->alias => $results);
```

Is there any specific reason to return the results this way or can I just return as:

return $results;

My concern is that if I don't return in the CakePHP specific format I might not be able to use some other built in functionality. I don't see anything specific about the need for this structure. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to CakePHP's data structure guidelines. The reason Cake uses the model name as the array key and the results as the value is because it makes it very easy to read when you have multiple tables returned in the same query - after all, Cake models are relational database maps and are built to be associative.

How you use the results from Cake's data results is up to you. Yes, there are times when the model name prefix annoys me and I find it useless, but most of the time it can be very useful to help you distinguish between multiple associated table results in one query.

If you don't think you'll ever need this and don't mind breaking Cake's data structure conventions, there's nothing wrong with breaking away from it - but if I were you I would create your API interface in a way where it conforms exactly to the structure that their built in datasources return (for current and future compatibility reasons mainly).

More info on creating a REST API datasource is [here in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html).

Comment: Thank you. There really isn't an option to return more than one table from this sort of API, but if this is a standard I will stick to it for consistency.